# Google Chrome clears :after-element left, all other browsers not

Tags: css, google-chrome

The following code will render a button (a link) with background images in the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-selectors to get a flexible cross-browising result. The problem is, only chrome doesn't get it (safari, I don't know).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="btn-container align-right more-info-btn">
        <a class="btn" href="#">Super Button<i class="arrow-after-right"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.btn-container .btn {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 24px;
    background: transparent url('http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/5052/kdti.png');
    padding: 0 6px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 21px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, FreeSans, Verdana, Tahoma, 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Luxi Sans', sans-serif;
}
.btn-container .btn:before {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    background: transparent url('http://img600.imageshack.us/img600/3825/6ppo.png') no-repeat;
    width: 4px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -10px;
    float: left;
}
.btn-container .btn:after {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    background: transparent url('http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/4803/b5zs.png') no-repeat;
    width: 4px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: -10px;
    float: right;
}
```

Button in Google Chrome:
[image: Button in Google Chrome]

Button in all other browsers:
[image: Button in all other browsers]

**jsFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/K7y4U/4/

I have already tried different float/clear combinations, but so far without success.

Comment: Why on earth do you need this workaround for a button like that? Why not just use a button or style a div?

Comment: ie8 support, no CssPie

Comment: @Dominic: have you tried it with div elements before and after the a-element? For me it does the same.

Comment: Loading all those separate assets for something so small isn't a good idea when you can create the same - with an acceptable fallback - using only CSS. No need for images in this task.

Answer (score 0):

Set a explicit width to .btn_container. That'll solve your problem. Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/K7y4U/6/

I did: `.btn-container .btn { width: 90px; }`

Comment: "...to get a flexible cross-browsing result..." - means: the button must be flexible, because the button text is sometimes longer.

Comment: in that case just add min-width: 90px;

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/K7y4U/20/

Floats and Inline Blocks don't play together.

```
.btn-container .btn {
    vertical-align:top;
    line-height:24px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: transparent url('http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/5052/kdti.png');
    padding: 0 0 0 6px;
    font-size: 11px;
    height:24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, FreeSans, Verdana, Tahoma, 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Luxi Sans', sans-serif;
    min-width: 90px
}
.btn-container .btn:before {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    background: transparent url('http://img600.imageshack.us/img600/3825/6ppo.png') no-repeat;
    width: 4px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
.btn-container .btn:after {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    background: transparent url('http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/4803/b5zs.png') no-repeat;
    width: 4px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
.btn-container .arrow-before-right:before, .btn-container .arrow-after-right:after, .arrow-link-container.arrow-before-right:before, .arrow-link-container.arrow-after-right:after {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent blue;
}
.btn-container .arrow-before-down:before, .btn-container .arrow-before-left:before, .btn-container .arrow-before-right:before, .btn-container .arrow-before-up:before, .btn-container .arrow-after-down:after, .btn-container .arrow-after-left:after, .btn-container .arrow-after-right:after, .btn-container .arrow-after-up:after, .arrow-link-container.arrow-before-down:before, .arrow-link-container.arrow-before-left:before, .arrow-link-container.arrow-before-right:before, .arrow-link-container.arrow-before-up:before, .arrow-link-container.arrow-after-down:after, .arrow-link-container.arrow-after-left:after, .arrow-link-container.arrow-after-right:after, .arrow-link-container.arrow-after-up:after {
    border-width: .4em .45em;
    border-style: solid;
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: .4em;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-top:7px;
}
```